# Show/hide a div by clicking a checkbox,not working

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

`.ds-drop-down` {
    background: url('../../images/light-grey-disclosure-arrow-down.png')no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ds-btn {
    height: 22px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    top: 63px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    left: 579px;  
}

#span-advanced-search {
    border: 2px solid blue;

    left: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
    background: green;
   display: block;
   visibility: visible;
   position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-1" class="ds-drop-down" role="button" data-tooltip="Show search options"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1"></input>
<div id="span-advanced-search">
 <label>Education Level:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Type of Learning Material:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Difficulty Level:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Author:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
</div>
```

I want to show `div`-> 'span-advanced-search' by clicking on the `checkbox`->'toggle-1'. Initially the `div` will be hidden and when the `checkbox` is unchecked then also the `div` must be hidden.
I have shared my code snippet above,it's not working,when i am clicking on the `checkbox` the `div` is not showing.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but hope it helps some way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="checkbox"){
                $("#span-advanced-search").toggle();
            }
          });
    });
```

```css
#span-advanced-search{
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="checkbox"></label>
</div>
<div id="span-advanced-search">
 <label>Education Level:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Type of Learning Material:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Difficulty Level:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Author:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
</div>
```

Comment: After getting the div->"span-advanced-search" open, when I am trying to click in any input box to write something in it,the div is getting closed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @SusmitaSadhu I edited the post, you need to use jquery on this, the above should work perfectly.

Comment: https://imgur.com/edit
This is my page,When i am click anywhere within the "Advanced Search Box",It's getting close. I also add jquery,as above said, but I can't prevent this, just for that i can't write anything within the box. Please help.

Comment: @SusmitaSadhu - However the image you linked is broken I could only imagine something is wrong with your CSS/Javascript.

Comment: sorry for previous one.
Please check this image-> http://imgur.com/MkHUNiv  
This is my page,When i am click anywhere within the "Advanced Search Box",It's getting close. I also add jquery,as above said, but I can't prevent this, just for that i can't write anything within the box. Please help.

Comment: @SusmitaSadhu Why do you want to create a form in a `<select>` in first place? Didn't you need checkbox for that? I would never create a form in a `<select>`, maybe that's the reason the form disappears when you click. (Because you selected the form option of the `<select>`. That's normal behavior.)

Comment: I am relatively new in html,css. @balintpekker , I can't understand what you want to say,can you please tell me elaborately? You are saying <select>,what is it?

Comment: @SusmitaSadhu The `<select>` is a HTML tag that you are using on the picture you provided. It is a drop-down list with options to choose from it. Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) for more info.